# Default headers and licenses

Tags: macos, xcode, compile

I am building a toolchain that I'd like to redistribute. In particular, I am building a GNUstep bundle for Mac OS X, in order to support cross-platform ObjC development - and some other stuff alongside.

Everything works so far, but I am missing the default headers, which arent there unless you have Xcode. I can't memorize if I created `/usr/include` myself by copying the files off the Xcode bundle or not.

Is there a way to obtain the default headers - like `sys/types.h` - for OS X?
And even more important: What is their license, and are they redistributable thru their license?

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/include` is already present on my Mavericks Installation(I have 178 files,14 symlink, 59 dir). So you probably did not copy them them (but Yes I've Xcode too).

About the licences, they are already present in the files themselves : For example `sys/types.h` is under the `Apple Public Source Licence` which allows you to redistribute it.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to obtain the header files without needing to install the whole bunch of xCode? I know enough people that are limited with their internet and aren't very able to download a GBs of xCode first.
Thanks for the info on the headers though - i should read the headerfiles then ^^